# Express does not wait for the promise

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

  await Auth.findOne({ userEmail }, { userLoginInfo: 0 }).then((auth) => {
    console.log('1');
    console.log(res.header); <---------- header sent after console.log('1')
    // Check if user exists
    if (auth === null) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ authFailedMessage: 'Email or password is incorrect' });
    } else if (auth !== null) {
      console.log('auuuuuuth')
      console.log(res.header)
      console.log('auuuuuuth13412312')
      bcrypt.compare(password, auth.password).then((isMatch) => {
        if(isMatch) {
          console.log(res.header)
          console.log('matched!')
          console.log(res.header)
        } else if (!isMatch) {
          console.log(res.header)
          console.log('hhhhh?!')
          console.log(res.header)
        }
      })
```

I am trying to verify users and then sending jwt in cookies. However, the res header fires off even before I do something about the result. I'd tried with new Promise(), however, in this case, it does not move on after the Promise returns the value. How can I send headers after I do something with mongoose query results that have been returned?

------ new code

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const logInEnvironment = browser(req.headers['user-agent']);
  const ipAddress = requestIp.getClientIp(req);
  const userEmail = req.body.userEmail.toLowerCase();
  const password = req.body.password;
  console.log('aa')
  console.log(res.header);
  // Form validation
  const validation = await validateLoginInput(req.body);
  console.log(res.header);
  console.log('ab')
  // Check validation
  if (!validation.isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(validation.errors);
  }
  console.log(res.header);
  console.log('ac')
  // Find user by email

  const auth = await Auth.findOne({ userEmail }, { userLoginInfo: 0 })
    console.log(`auuuuth? ${auth}`);
    console.log(res.header);
    console.log('ad')

    if(auth !== null) {
      console.log('ahiuhiuhaisudf!')
    } else {
      console.log('whaitoh!?')
    }
 
});
```

------ console.log

```
aa
[Function: header]
a <------ from 'const validation = await validateLoginInput(req.body)'
[Function: header]
ab
[Function: header]
ac
auuuuth? {
  termsandconditions: {
    agreed: true,
  },

}
[Function: header]
ad
ahiuhiuhaisudf!
```

Comment: Writing a middleware would fix that

Comment: Where exactly is your problem in your code?  The only response the code you currently have in your question ever sends is the error response.  The other code path does not send any response.  So, where are you trying to wait for a promise?  FYI, `await` NEVER waits for a plain callback like `bcrypt.compare()` uses.  `await` ONLY waits on promises.  I'm not sure if that's related to your question or not as I can't tell what/where your problem actually is.

Comment: That was what i have thought. I tried to attach cookie header with returned value, however, as I marked in the code, response was sent right after console.log(‘1’) was executed. I think it was why i kept getting ‘cannot send headers after the header was already sent’ error. Im a noob, so i really don’t know why it returns console.log(res)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in your code with regards to how you are 'awaiting' the promise. You seem to have appended a `.then()` to the promise while using the `await` keyword, they both serve the same purpose.

```
await Auth.findOne({ userEmail }, { userLoginInfo: 0 }).then((auth) => {
```

You should try removing the `.then()` block and store the resolved promise in a variable instead:

```
const auth = await Auth.findOne({ userEmail }, { userLoginInfo: 0 });
//Do what you want with the 'auth' here
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I changed the code to however header is returned first. I just added the new code + return console.log.

Comment: I did not understand what you're problem is exactly, but if you're trying to set headers, use `res.set(field [, value])` as mentioned in the express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Comment: I wanted to send cookies (with the value that is coming from promises). And, res.cookie was not working because the header was already sent.